# CMake link library from external directory

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

```
\lib
 mylib.so
 \- inc
   \- mod1
   \- mod2
   \- another_lib
\examples
  \- common_inc 
  \- example1
    CMakeLists.txt
    \- src
    \- inc
  \- example2
     ...
```

I'm trying to link shared lib mylib.so to executable but CMake throws error
 `Imported target "mylib" includes non-existent path in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.`

**How to link shared library from directory outside of `example1`?**

Yeah, there are a lot of similar questions but nobody had this issue.

I followed [Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) answer and came out with this CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (example1 CXX)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

set (SRC
                "src/main.cpp"
                "src/mod1.cpp"
)

set (INC
                "inc/mod1.hpp"
)


add_library(mylib SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}../../lib/mylib.so"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}../../lib/inc"
)

add_executable (example1 ${SRC})
target_include_directories(example1 PRIVATE "inc")
target_include_directories(example1 PRIVATE "../common_inc") 
target_link_libraries(example1 mylib)
```

Comment: Path `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}../../lib/inc` is actually doesn't exist: you forgot slash (`/`) after `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`. The same issue is with *IMPORTED_LOCATION* property.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Silly mistake... You are right, It's working now.